# F suffix on number assigned to double

Tags: c++, c

I am aware that suffixing a floating point number with f lets the compiler know that it is a float rather than a double. Which is important to prevent unnecessary casting when operating on floats rather than doubles. However in some code I have been provided by an external company I have seen the following for example:

```
double i = 1.4f;
```

Now what I'm wondering is what happens in this case? Will the compiler silently ignore the 'f' and it is just something that has no bearing on anything and I can safely ignore?

I then wondered that if numbers are assigned to doubles with an f suffix elsewhere, not just on initialisation would that be a different case that acts differently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Relevant quotes from the C standard:

§6.4.4.2 paragraph 4

> If suffixed by the letter f or F, it has type float.

paragraph 5

> Floating constants are converted to internal format as if at translation-time.

paragraph 7

> The translation-time conversion of floating constants should match the execution-time conversion of character strings by library functions, such as strtod, given matching inputs suitable for both conversions, the same result format, and default execution-time rounding.

Assuming IEEE-754 numerics `1.4f` produces the value:

```
1.39999997615814208984375
```

whereas `1.4` has the value:

```
1.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375.
```

Comment: I would put -1 for sadness - but I am not that cruel. So instead a +1 for an insight

Comment: Also +1 for the values, but it would be even better if you chose a value where including or omitting the f suffix changes whether the value is above or below the numerical exact value. IIRC 1.2 or 1.3 is such a case.

Comment: @R..: yes, 1.2 is such a case.

Comment: Really interesting answer. I am not totally sure but does that mean in some cases using an f and not using an f on the same value on 2 different doubles might make a comparison (using epsilon etc) inaccurate? Also, if I may also ask, what do you mean about 1.2 or 1.3?

Comment: @Firedragon: Yes, that's right.  `1.4 == 1.4f` should evaluate to `false`.  **R..** was pointing out that 1.2 has the property that the literal `1.2` has a value smaller than 1.2, whereas `1.2f` is larger than 1.2.

Comment: @EdHeal: There is nothing sad about understanding how your code works. =)

Comment: @Firedragon As the answer clearly stated, `1.4f` and `1.4` are two different numbers (at least in the usual floating point representation).  As such, they will compare unequal.

Comment: @Stephen Canon - It was tongue in cheek but you did look up and type in those long values! BUT - I did give you a +1 for an insight. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @EdHeal: Oh, I know.  It's really not hard, though; a two-line C program and copy + paste.

Answer (score 3):

A good compiler should convert 1.4f directly to double.

A compliant compiler will conver 1.4f to `float` format, then convert the value to `double`, then assign the value to `i`.

By the way, historically from days of FORTRAN, a variable named `i` usually holds integer values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible that in the case of a compliant compiler as you say, that casting could affect performance, no matter how slight? Also, I didn't know that about the i variable but in this case it was just an example picked out of the air but it is an interesting thing to learn so thanks for that.

Comment: @Firedragon:  Casting should not affect performance.  The conversion to double should take place during the compiler or translation phase.  The number will still be stored in memory and loaded into the variable as usual.

Comment: The literal `1.4` does not need to be converted to `double`, because it already *is* of type double.

Comment: @FredOverflow:  My mistake, typo, should be 1.4f.